# NEXT.JS (Pages) - Error with Pinecone Database in Edge Environment: "edgeFunction is not a function"

Tags: typescript, next.js, edge-function

I'm experiencing an issue with Pinecone storage in an Edge environment. When I use Pinecone storage, the application breaks, and I receive an error message stating "edgeFunction is not a function." However, if I remove the function and its call (createContext and contextChain), the code works fine. The functions FetchChatbotByID and DeductMessages also perform their tasks without issues. I have been trying to resolve this problem for three days now and would appreciate any help. Below is the code snippet where the issue occurs:

```
import { StreamingTextResponse, LangChainStream, Message } from "ai";
import { ChatOpenAI } from "langchain/chat_models/openai";
import { AIChatMessage, HumanChatMessage } from "langchain/schema";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { supabase } from '@/lib/supabase';
import { Chatbot } from '@/types/database';
import { PINECONE_INDEX_NAME } from '@/config/pinecone';
import { pinecone } from '@/lib/pinecone/pinecone-client';
import { PineconeStore } from 'langchain/vectorstores/pinecone';
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from 'langchain/embeddings/openai';
import { ConversationalRetrievalQAChain } from 'langchain/chains';
import { BufferMemory } from 'langchain/memory';

export const runtime = "edge";

export async function createContext(chatbot_id: string) {
  const index = await pinecone.Index(PINECONE_INDEX_NAME);
  const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(
    new OpenAIEmbeddings({}),
    {
      pineconeIndex: index,
      textKey: 'text',
      namespace: Array.isArray(chatbot_id) ? chatbot_id[0] : chatbot_id,
    }
  );

  const GPT3 = new ChatOpenAI({
    temperature: 0, 
    modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo', 
  });

  const chain = ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(
    GPT3,
    vectorStore.asRetriever(),
    {
      returnSourceDocuments: true,
      memory: new BufferMemory({
        memoryKey: 'chat_history',
        inputKey: 'question',
        outputKey: 'text',
        returnMessages: true,
      }),
      questionGeneratorChainOptions: {
        llm: GPT3,
      },
    },
  );

  return chain;
}

async function deductMessages(user_id: string): Promise<number> {
  // Получите текущий message_limit
  console.log("Fetching message_limit for user:", user_id);
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('user_message_limits')
    .select('message_limit')
    .eq('user_id', user_id);

  console.log("Fetched data:", data);

  if (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch message_limit:", error);
    throw error;
  }

  if (!data || data.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("No subscription found for the user");
  }

  const currentLimit = data[0]?.message_limit;
  if (currentLimit === undefined || currentLimit < 1) {
    throw new Error("Not enough messages");
  }

  const updatedLimit = currentLimit - 1;

  // Обновите message_limit
  const { error: updateError } = await supabase
    .from('user_message_limits')
    .update({ message_limit: updatedLimit })
    .eq('user_id', user_id);

  if (updateError) {
    console.error("Failed to update message_limit:", updateError);
    throw updateError;
  }

  return updatedLimit;
}

async function fetchChatbotById(chatbot_id: string): Promise<Chatbot[]> {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('chatbots')
    .select('*')
    .eq('chatbot_id', chatbot_id);

  if (error) {
    console.error("Query execution failed:", error);
    throw error; // or return { error };
  }

  return data;
}

export default async function handler(req: NextRequest) {
  const messages = await req.json();
  const data = req.headers.get('Authorization');
  const chatbot_id = data as string;
  console.log('Chatbot_id:', chatbot_id);

  const chatbotData = await fetchChatbotById(chatbot_id);
  const chatbot: Chatbot = chatbotData[0];

  const userId = chatbot.user_id as string;

  await deductMessages(userId);
  const contextChain = await createContext(chatbot_id);


  const { stream, handlers } = LangChainStream();

  interface Message {
    role: string;
    content: string;
  }

  const llm = new ChatOpenAI({
    modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    streaming: true,
    temperature: 0.9,
    maxTokens: 200,
    openAIApiKey: '###'
  });
  console.log(messages)
  llm.call(
    messages.messages.map((m: Message) =>
      m.role == "user" ? new HumanChatMessage(m.content) : new AIChatMessage(m.content)
    ),
    {},
    [handlers]
  )
    .catch(console.error);

  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}
```

I tried to move this function to a separate file with props passing and removing edgeFunction - in this case, I would have to rewrite a significant part of the code.